# Sound not adding to dictionary container

Tags: c#, audio, xna

I am making sounds in XNA and I want to add them to a dictionary so I can store and call them whenever I want.  For example, store a jump sound, call it when jumping in the player class.

Here is the code:

```
this.soundEffectInfo = new SoundEffectInfo(this, "BackgroundSound", "Assets\\Sounds\\RaceSound", 0.9f, 20, 20, true);

soundManager.add(soundEffectInfo);
soundEffectInfo.SOUNDEFFECT.Play();

this.soundEffectInfo = new SoundEffectInfo(this, "JumpSound", "Assets\\Sounds\\JumpSound", 0.9f, 20, 20, true);
soundManager.add(soundEffectInfo);
```

`soundEffectInfo` is a `SoundEffectInfo` object which takes in a `SoundEffectInstance`.
`SoundManager` is a class container for these instances.

The error I'm getting is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in RATEV2.exe
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Where exactly does you error occur? I don't see code calling your jump-sound...

Answer (score 0):

Smells like you didn't instance your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the entire class to get a sense of what's wrong, but rather than put all sound effects into one dictionary try creating a static class that holds references to all your sound effect files, here's how I do it in my games:

```
    public static class SoundEffects
    {
           public static SoundEffect jump; 

           public static void LoadSounds(ContentManager content)
           {
                jump = content.Load<SoundEffect>("location); 
           }
    }
```

You can then just call `SoundEffects.jump.Play();` anywhere that is needed, you can also write a static SoundManager class to adjust volumes and when things play when needed.